# I have been working on a ROR app and now when I try and run it on herokuapp, there is an application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using the One Month rails program and on the section "Paperclip to Amazon S3 Images on Heroku" my application began to fail.

When I run heroku logs:

```
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304275+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304284+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304293+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304291+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304289+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304296+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304297+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304301+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304307+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304310+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304333+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304303+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304326+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304329+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304305+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304344+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304347+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304341+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304339+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304362+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304355+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304356+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-04-23T16:19:30.304359+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-23T16:19:31.217505+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-23T16:19:31.218307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-23T16:19:31.206496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-23T16:19:35.058419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 11559 -e production`
2015-04-23T16:19:40.206900+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:11559
2015-04-23T16:19:40.206903+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-04-23T16:19:40.206904+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-04-23T16:19:40.206878+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207887+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': /app/app/models/pin.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
2015-04-23T16:19:40.206949+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207891+00:00 app[web.1]:    :storage => :S3,
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207893+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207900+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207902+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207915+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207920+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207922+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207923+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207925+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207930+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207932+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207973+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207977+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207979+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207984+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207986+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207988+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207996+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.207998+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208012+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208016+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208018+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208287+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208289+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208291+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208021+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208025+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208027+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208030+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208034+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208039+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208044+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208048+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208051+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208294+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208295+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208297+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-04-23T16:19:40.208300+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-04-23T16:19:41.128835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-23T16:19:41.139969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-23T16:21:29.387954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ktl-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=82ca3dca-f77e-48e8-9d16-17fd39d2435d fwd="76.105.6.149" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-23T16:21:28.646509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ktl-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=f2440a57-09cd-4242-9f16-27688b5eb3e2 fwd="76.105.6.149" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here is my gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end


group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
#Sets paperclip to upload images to amazon s3
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
end
```

Comment: `2015-04-23T16:19:40.207887+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require': /app/app/models/pin.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)` looks like the likely issue.